# Is the U.S.A. America?

Tags: north-american-english

Why North Americans think America it is only the U.S. and the rest of the continent it is not?

Comment: Most folks I know use the word in accordance with what the [dictionaries say](http://www.onelook.com/?w=America&ls=a); that is, they understand the word _America_ could refer to the nation **or** refer to the continent(s). The word can be used in more than one way, depending on the context.

Comment: Related: [*Can I use “US-American” to disambiguate “American”? If not, what can I use?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/87645/21009).

Comment: This is a [loaded question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question). Stack Exchange does not accept loaded or rhetorical questions. Back up your premise. As it stands it will be easily contradicted by a random world map printed in the US.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure North Americans, or anyone else, do think that. *America* is short for *United States of America*, just as *Britain* is, not entirely accurately, short for *United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland*. It will normally be obvious from the context whether the word refers to the sovereign state of the USA, or to the continent as a whole.

Comment: And _England_ is often used to label eleven men wearing football shirts (or cricket whites), and _salt_ to label the particular salt, sodium chloride. These are examples of the trope _synecdoche_ ( http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples/examples-of-synecdoche.html ) .

Comment: Canadians are of course from North America, but not all of them like to be considered as US-Citizens.

Comment: Mexicans, and other small countries, consider themselves to be Mesoamericans, not North-Americans.

Comment: Monroe declaration means :"all the New World belongs to the USA, or at least the fate of all these countries"

Comment: @MarkThorin - That's an interesting paraphrase of the [Monroe doctrine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monroe_doctrine#The_Doctrine). I wouldn't call it a very accurate one.